# How can I deploy my project which is private and is on enterprise account on heroku?

Tags: github, heroku, enterprise

I have my project on university's GitHub account which is private and I am trying to deploy it on heroku.

How can Heroku access such a (private) repo?

Answer (score 0):

First get an OAuth token from GitHub

```
 $ curl -u '<GitHub Username>' -d '{"scopes":["repo"],"note":"OAuth access for Heroku deployment"}' https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

See for instance "[Installing a Gem on Heroku from a Private GitHub Repo](https://gist.github.com/masonforest/4048732#installing-a-gem-on-heroku-from-a-private-github-repo)"

Then make sure heroku will use it:

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN=<my-read-only-token>
```

See "[Setting Up Private GitHub Repos with Bundler on Heroku](https://gist.github.com/hone/b0c0093374097313ab7f)".